# Can submit contact form without google recaptcha v2 validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, recaptcha

I have used a contact form in php and added google recaptcha on it. But I can submit the form without recaptcha validation. How can I make this recaptcha as required. I have already tried some solutions, but none of them worked for me. I appreciate your answers, Thanks

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="" id="fsrep-contact-form">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
    <tr id="fname">
      <td>First Name <span>*</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lname">
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="emailid">
      <td>Email <span>*</span></td>
      <td><input type="email" name="email" id="mail" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="phone-no">
      <td>Cell Phone <span>*</span></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="phone" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Please give us any other details you would like, that would help us to help you find your next home</td>
      <td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" id="rcaptcha" name="googlecaptcha" required data-sitekey="6LffZpsUAAAAAEC_KyN4KauhSSmKdRf9SVR5aVJD" data-callback="correctCaptcha"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT INQUIRY" id="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: On a side note why aren't you using v3?

Comment: You need to check that the post of the captcha is true and that the key is correct https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one and it works for me:

You have a "data-callback" attribute

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="rcaptcha" name="googlecaptcha" required data-sitekey="YOUR KEY" **data-callback="correctCaptcha"**></div>
```

simply create a function with the name **correctCaptcha**

```
var recaptchachecked=false; 
function correctCaptcha() {
    recaptchachecked = true;
}
```

Then with your form you hold it til you validate if the recaptchachecked variable is true, then proceed.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return isreCaptchaChecked(event)">
..
..
</form>

function isreCaptchaChecked()
{
  e.preventDefault();
  return recaptchachecked;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried this, but nothing happens when I click on the submit button whether captcha is checked or not. as if I am clicking on empty spaces.